# Using page link from home page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Ive generated MVC5 application ,code first and scaffold the controller and View.

By default I got home page and in the page upper in black there is text buttons for `home about contact` that when you press on it you routed to other page .

I want to change it that when I press on about for example it will open a page that are located in a **different project**,(also mvc project)

Can anyone help me figure out the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to hard-code the link. You can't use something like `Html.ActionLink` to get a URL in another project. It only works with the current project and its routes.

Answer (score 1):

Use for instance an `a` tag and assign the attribute `href` to your link: example `http://www.yoursecondmvc.com/theController/theAction` or if you running the project locally it will look like `http://localhost:numberport/theController/theAction`

```
 <a href=”http://www.yoursecondmvc.com/theController/theAction”>Go there</a>
```

Or

```
 <a href=”http://localhost:numberport/theController/theAction”>Go there</a>
```

If it is used by IIS express